# Java virtual machine properties to disable breakpoints

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am looking for a way to automatically disable breakpoints while debugging a program, the disabling must be made automatically and transparant to the programmer.

I came up with the VirtualMachine class which appears in 2 java packages:

1. com.sun.jdi
2. com.sun.tools.attach

I am looking for a way to disable the breakpoints using those classes. The problem with the first one (as far as I understand) is that its used when you write a debugger so when I check the loaded VMs by calling this library I receive none since I call it from the virtual machine which I try to manipulate.

My hopes are now drained into the second method and I came up with the following manner to retrieve the loaded VMs:

```
List<VirtualMachineDescriptor> vms = VirtualMachine.list(); //its com.sun.tools.attach VM
for (VirtualMachineDescriptor virtualMachineDescriptor : vms) {

        try {
            VirtualMachine v = virtualMachineDescriptor.provider().attachVirtualMachine(virtualMachineDescriptor.id());
.......
```

This code throws exceptions specifying `Unable to attach to 32-bit process running under WOW64` on some of the VMs but some are succesfully loaded. (I know it sounds bad). I wasn't managed to figure out what are the VMs that are loaded but I still want to try to manipulate them - learn from the experience.

from the VM I can retrieve the properties class using:

```
Properties systemProperties = v.getAgentProperties();
```

It has some properties such as `sun.jvm.args`,`sun.jvm.flags` etc.. those must be the arguments that the VM receive while it was initiated. I searched but couldn't find for flags which disable breakpoints or something similar I could use for this purpose. I guess that the properties can be changed on the fly since there is a `setProperty` method for the `properties` class.

One more thing that might be usefull is the fact that the extra calls to the code are invoked via instrumented instructions. I was hoping that I could turn the breakpoints off at the beginning of the instrumentation code and turn it on again at its end.

Are there such flags which might be usefull?

Comment: What exactly is your use case that you want to start an application in debug mode but skip all the breakpoints? Usually that is exactly what I use debugging for.

Comment: @hotzst Hi, I have pieces of code where I might put a breakpoint but I want to stop there with the debugger only when the code is invoked by user operations. Think about an update that is called both every second and when a user clicks a button, I want the debugger to stop only when the user clicks and not automatically every second. Hope it makes sense if not I will try to explain it better.

Comment: So place the breakpoint inside the action that is executed onclick.

Comment: @hotzst yes this is a solution but it doesn't suit my needs since I dont want the developer to be aware of the programs logic and dont want to restrict his actions